# Calculate conditional probability of poisson r.vs

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be annual number of hurricanes hitting city X and $Y$ be the
> number of hurricanes hitting city Y. X and Y are independent poisson
> with respective means $1.7$ and $2.3$. Calculate $P(X-Y|X+Y=3)$.

### Attempt

Notice

$$ P( X-Y=k  | X+Y=3) P(X+Y=3) = P(X-Y=k \cap X+Y=3) $$

Now,

$$ P(X-Y=k \cap X+Y=3) = P(X-Y=k)P(X+Y=3) $$

now, we can find $p_{X+Y}(x,y)$ . we have

$$ p_{X+Y}(x,y) = p_X(x) p_Y(y) = \frac{e^{-1.7} 1.7^x}{x!} \cdot \frac{e^{-2.3} 2.3^y}{y!} $$

$$ P(X+Y=3) = p_{X+Y}(2,1) = \frac{e^{-1.7} 1.7^2}{2!} \cdot \frac{e^{-2.3} 2.3^1}{1!} $$

but, then we also need to add to this $p_{X+Y}(1,2)$, $p_{X+Y}(3,0)$ and $p_{X+Y}(0,3)$. but this seem to make the problem way too complicated in terms of calculations. Am I doing this problem correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but this seem to make the problem way too complicated in terms of calculations. Am I doing this problem correctly?

Yes. Well,   $p_{X+Y}(3)=p_{X,Y}(0,3)+p_{X,Y}(1,2)+p_{X,Y}(2,1)+p_{X,Y}(3,0)$

However, to make calulations easier, consider that the sum of independent Poisson random variables is a Poison random variable who's rate is the sum of their rates. ...

---

Also, the correct application for independence in the denominator is via:

$$\mathsf P(X-Y=k\cap X+Y=3) ~{=\mathsf P(2X=k+3 \cap 2Y=3-k)\\=\mathsf P(X=\frac{k+3}2)~\mathsf P(Y=\frac{3-k}2)}$$

Comment: even though $X$ and $Y$ are independent this doesnt mean $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ are independent. correct?

Comment: Right. That's why you should rearrange the simultaneous equations to seperate the  terms of $X,Y$

Comment: I get this part, but then to obtain the solution we need to consider different cases for $X-Y$ how can we tell in between what values $X-Y$ should lie?

Comment: You know the four values of $(X,Y)$ that make $X+Y=3$.  That tells you the four values $X-Y$ takes under that condition.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- $P(X-Y=k\mid X+Y=3)=P\left(X=\frac{k+3}{2}\mid X+Y=3\right)$
- $P(X+Y=3) = \dfrac{e^{-(1.7+2.3)} (1.7+2.3)^3}{3!}$
- you get interesting results if you expand $(1.7+2.3)^3$
- Given $X+Y=3$, you will find $X$ is binomially distributed with parameters $n=3$ and $p=\dfrac{1.7}{1.7+2.3} =0.425$

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** If $D = X-Y|X+Y=3,$ then $V = (D+3)/2 \sim \mathsf{Binom}(3, .425).$

In the figure below, the histogram is for simulated values of $V$ and the 
open circles are for $\mathsf{Binom}(3, .425).$ [Based on a million values of
$X+Y$ and about 195,000 cases with $X-Y = 3.$]

[image]